# Illustrator generated SVG doesn't work on a web page

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, svg, css

Using Illustrator CC 2015, when I save an AI file as a SVG then apply this SVG file as a CSS background-image, it displays nothing. Why?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's answered on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185434/using-svg-as-background-image

Comment: SVG does appear on the web page in the case of the question you linked, I have a different problem.

Comment: how can we help without seeing any code? :-/

Comment: drake035: we are really going to need a lot more info to answer this question. Is the SVG an image file you linked, or did you include the code in your HTML? Did you use the 'Save As' or 'Export' dialog? Did you enable Minify and/or Responsive? Etc

Comment: You are sure your css background-image is pointing to the correct resource name?

Comment: @PieBie: as I said, I used it as a CSS background image so no code in HTML. Silly-V: yes definitely. Vinny: there is no code I can show even if I wanted to, there's no code involved in this question at all...

Answer (score 3):

Some things to look out for:

**1. AI: Use the Export dialog**

In Illustrator, make sure you use the Export as dialog (File > Export > Export As...). The Export dialog was made specifically for exporting files for web use, while the Save As dialog was made for saving a file for later reopening in AI. This means Export gives you a lot of extra options the Save As dialog doesn't include.

The default options are usually good, except in certain cases (e.g. when you want to manipulate the SVG later, it's better not to minify it so you can actually read the code). It's best to leave it at responsive unless you want it at a specific size. But since SVG is a vector file, there really is no need to not make it responsive.

[image: AI export dialog]
[click for full resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev4ja.jpg)

**2. Code: Use a separate SVG file**

In most cases, it is unnecessary to include the SVG in you HTML. Just Export it from AI and use it like you would a JPG or PNG. I find this a lot easier to work with, because SVG files don't need a separate workflow from other images.

Here's a [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/PieBie/6e1o8mcs/1/) with a working SVG background.

Comment: Thanks a lot @PieBie but in EXPORT AS I have a list of formats, none is SVG...

Comment: Here's the Adobe help article about exporting as SVG: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/export-svg.html

Comment: Thanks. Actually I did come across this very article before posting this question! I don't understand why I don't have any SVG option in EXPORT menu formats...